# quitar horas entre x y x

Tags: python

tengo una lista con todas las horas en Python

---

horas = ["00:00","01:00","02:00","03:00","04:00","05:00","06:00","07:00","08:00","09:00","10:00","11:00","12:00","13:00","14:00","15:00","16:00","17:00","18:00","19:00","20:00","21:00","22:00","23:00"]

---

lo que quiero hacer es por ejemplo quitar las horas que estén entre "14:00" y "16:00"

para que la lista quede así

---

horas=["00:00","01:00","02:00","03:00","04:00","05:00","06:00","07:00","08:00","09:00","10:00","11:00","12:00","13:00","17:00","18:00","19:00","20:00","21:00","22:00","23:00"]

---

alguien sabría como hacer esto

de antemano muchas gracias

Comment: Bienvenido David Soto Rivera a Stack Overflow en español, te sugiero que hagas el [tour] y de paso ganes tu primer medalla, también es muy importante que leas [ask] para poder mejorar tu pregunta y que sea bien recibida por la comunidad mejorando así, tus chances de obtener buenas respuestas.

Comment: Por favor agrega lo que hayas intentado para resolverlo

Answer (score 0):

ya lo tengo

```
 horas = ["00:00","01:00","02:00","03:00","04:00","05:00","06:00","07:00","08:00","09:00","10:00","11:00","12:00","13:00","14:00","15:00","16:00","17:00","18:00","19:00","20:00","21:00","22:00","23:00"]

horaInicio="14:00"
horaFin="16:00"
i=0
horasAborrar=[]

for i in range(len(horas)):
  if horas[i]==horaInicio:
    while horas[i]<=horaFin:
        print(horas[i])
        horasAborrar.append(horas[i])
        i+=1
for i in horasAborrar:
  if i in horas:
     horas.remove(i)

print(horas)
```

Comment: Lo puedes hacer en una sola línea: `res = [x for x in horas if (x < "14:00" or x > "16:00")]`

Comment: Tal y como está redactada, tu respuesta no es clara. Por favor, pulsa en [edit] para añadir detalles adicionales que ayuden a los demás a entender cómo esto responde a la pregunta formulada. Puedes encontrar más información sobre cómo escribir buenas respuestas [en el centro de ayuda](/help/how-to-answer).